# How do I render a zone or a widget from inside an Orchard alternate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I'm trying to reproduce [this layout](http://friendlythem.es/html_themes/venus/blog_post.html) in Orchard. So far, I've got most of the stuff worked out by using an alternate for my blog post detail (`Content-BlogPost.Detail.cshtml`). The problem is that the layout I've created looks something like this:

[image]

My first question is, does this layout make any sense? Is there a better way to accomplish this result (that is, getting the archives displayed in line with the content)?

Secondly, is there a way to render a zone (or a widget) from inside my alternate? I tried doing `@Display(Model.Archives)`, where `Archives` is the name of my zone, but obviously the blog detail model doesn't define an Archives property. I also considered manually calling out to the Blog Archives shape with something like

```
@Display(New.Parts_Blogs_BlogArchives(new { Blog: blog, Archives: ???})
```

But I don't know how to populate that second argument.

What's the right way to make this layout happen in Orchard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with this layout is that the *Archives* zone is being placed inside the markup for the blog post. That makes things harder to render, but not impossible.

*The solution would be to render the whole layout zone inside your alternate, exactly like you said. You can display the main, top-level layout zones from every shape like this: `@Display(Layout.Archives)`. `Layout` is a property that gives you access to the main Layout shape.*

I'd do it like this:

1. **Add a zone called Archives in your Theme.txt manifest file** (Zones section) that will be a placeholder for blog archives widget. Make sure you would **not** render it in `Layout.cshtml` file. This zone will be strictly for blog post purposes (you can also give it a different name to note this).
2. **Create a shape alternate for blog post, like you did, and call `Display(Layout.Archives)`** in appropriate place. This will render the whole zone *inside* the blog post markup.
3. **Put the blog archives widget in the Archives zone.**

Now, every time any blog post gets rendered, it would also render the archives widget.

Comment: Awesome. Where do I learn all this stuff about Orchard? The deeper I go, the more there is to learn. :)

Comment: Docs and hands-on experience is the best way to go:)

Comment: Peek at the code of existing modules that do interesting things.